# How to select corresponding value on last month on SQL Server (I think it is a simple query)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

[image]

I need to make query that returns the corresponding value for each ***code*** on last month, like the following:

[image]

Like I said, I think it is a simple query, but I can't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `lag()`:

```
select t.*, lag(value) over (partition by code order by date) as value_last_month
from t;
```

In older versions of SQL Server, you can use `apply`:

```
select t.*, t2.value as value_last_month
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.code = t.code and t2.date < t.date
      order by date desc
     ) t2;
```

Comment: I cannot use LAG function, the version of SQL Server is old.